# How to capture all system configurations and apply to remote machines?

Tags: arch-linux, rsync, raspberry-pi, remote, puppet

I have bunch of raspberry pies that I have installed arch-linux on. On regular basis, I make changes to the system configurations. For instance I install services, change connection settings, move files around and basically all sort of administrative tasks.

The goal is to make all of these changes on one RPi and then apply them to all other RPies.

One solution is to take an image of the SD card and burn it to other RPies but the problem is that the RPies would be remote and I would not have physical access to them.

One other solution I can think of is using `rsync` on almost all directories. I am not sure how efficient this could be due to amount of traffic going over the Internet.

Also I think this can be done with Chef or Puppet. But I am not sure if they are the right tool for this job.

Any idea on how this sort of problem is usually addressed?

Comment: You are on the right track. Use Ansible/Chef/Puppet or some similar configuration management system.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a tool like [blueprint](http://devstructure.com/blueprint/) to reverse-engineer your machine config. It can create puppet modules, chef cookbooks or shellscripts that you can modify and apply on another machine.